# IE8 - SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, jspdf

I am getting below error in IE8, When I load the jspdf.debug.js file

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'**

and

```
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
```

I have searched with google, did not get any relevant answer.

Please help me to resolve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Which library you are using? check if that library is using `canvas`.

Comment: getContext is only used for canvas, so somewhere something is trying to create a canvas, which isn't supported in IE8

Comment: ok. How can I fix the issue? can you help me?

Comment: I am using jspdf lib and jquery

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: If it's indeed uses canvas, try plugging in https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/ library which simulates Canvas in older IE

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the recently added PNG support, and fixed on the latest release*, just pick a newer *dist* file from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/dist

*: You won't have PNG support there, though.